# Need advice improving my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I anticipated that "where is documentation" and certain triggering words would cause readers to assume that I've done louse/none effort or that it's a homework. So I put in a very nice disclaimer explaining that in advance.

I also got a good answer but alongside with it, I got uncommented downvotes accompanied by an answer that's a clear hit-and-miss. So naturally, I fear that I might have formulated the question in a bad way, still.

Would it be OK to ask for a few pointers on how to improve it? The contents are useful but the downvote implies that there's room for improvement. Three users can't have a bad day simultaneously, right?

It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552619/cant-find-documentation-on-a-cool-angular-feature-for-two-way-binding).

Comment: It doesn't really look like a problem you're having; it's asking where the documentation for the solution you already got resides.  Ideally, good answers should have that, but we focus on solving the problem itself.  Asking another question for people to source the solution isn't really a question.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not sure I understood the comment. I didn't have the docs' location at the time I asked a question. I only had the experience of the feature. Or am I missing your point entirely?

Comment: Yeah, but is knowing the docs' location an actual programming problem you're experiencing?  I'd lean towards not, as you're not actually having a problem with your code.  If anything, that source should've been part of the answer on your previous question, and not necessitated a separate question to get that information.  Makoto's got a good point about defining how the code works, but I disagree that is specifically what you're asking.

Comment: Aside, your comments are needlessly aggressive, e.g. `You might want to re-read the question, mate. You kind of missed the point a bit. Or, rather, you missed it totally.` No need for this, you reap what you sow.

Comment: @jpp Point taken. How would you prefer to address a user who apparently didn't read the question, simply reacting to an assumption? Perhaps a plain *please read the full question* would be more appropriate. What do you think?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana - if someone didn't give you an answer that was in the ballpark, it's easier to downvote them and move on.  There's no need to engage in conversation; the fact is that their answer didn't help you.

Comment: @Makoto Interesting point. I understand that there's room for improvement. Just for the record, I wish to point out that my aim wasn't to aggressively attack the user. I actually hoped that by addressing his approach, I can enable him to really read the question and either remove his answer or (even better) to provide a relevant one. Also, I was hoping that said user might be more thorough for the upcoming occasions too, if instructed firmly. I'll definitely try to formulate my input more friendly. The irony was supposed to ease it up a bit but apparently, not successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a really good question.

There is a subtle yet explicit difference between someone *asking for documentation, tutorials or references*, and someone explaining a piece of code and asking if that behavior is defined in a concrete and tacit way.  **You are asking for the latter**, and those are the kinds of document-y questions which have lasting value here.

People may be reading the question a little too quickly to pick up on that difference, but it's very much the case that:

- Your question is narrowly focused
- You are asking about a very explicit use case
- You're not really looking for just any ol' documentation

...so I think it's fine the way it is.

Comment: I'm happy I did a good job asking. I'm displeased about the "community driven decision". It only proves my point that people are too trigger happy (probably because they're fed up with the questions belonging to the first category of yours). Thanks for the feed-back, anyway.